# ADF Storage event trigger when there are multiple files in different folders

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to trigger my ADF pipeline when three files arrives in paths : container/folder1/file1.parquet
container/folder2/file2.parquet
container/folder3/file3.parquet

Only when these 3 subfolders gets new files(files will be overwritten) should the ADF pipeline trigger.

How can we achieve this?

Update : This should be an AND condition, ie - the pipeline should be triggered only after all 3 files arrive or gets updated.

Comment: Do you have specific file names or are they subject to change

Comment: filenames are specific, wont change

Comment: so if they are specific, its easy, as per my second step in the updated answer, you can mention directly the file paths in GetMetadata activity and solve this.  Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: Glad it  helps 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

There is no out-of-the-box feature to achieve this, you can share your idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

What you can do is

1. Setup a Storage event triggered pipeline on first destination i.e. `container/folder1/file1.parquet` as I have explained earlier.
2. Then after maybe waiting for few secs using [WaitActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-wait-activity) use [`Get Metadata activity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) with Field list
   Argument as `Child items` to get list of files in the folder

   **or**

   `LookupAcitivty` chain to look for files at `container/folder2/file2.parquet` and `container/folder3/file3.parquet` with  `file list path` property. [File list examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#file-list-examples)
3. Then you can hold the results in variables for convenience and using Conditional activities like `IfActivity` compare to see if all the files exist, if `True` you can proceed with further activities you plan to design in the pipeline when the three files arrived.

---

*In case of explicit availability or 3 files seperately..*

You can simply use 3 different new triggers for same pipeline. Each with different folder as its `Blob path ends with` property in trigger.

Here is sample trigger for first folder i.e. `container/folder1/file1.parquet`

You can also mention like `.parquet` using patterns to match files with different names dynamically.

[Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory): That Blob path begins with and ends with are the only pattern matching allowed in Storage Event Trigger.

[image]

Similarly you can create 2 more for `container/folder2/file2.parquet` and `container/folder3/file3.parquet`

[image]

Comment: it should be an AND condition, not OR ie only when all 3 files are updated or overwritten, then the pipeline should be triggered...

Comment: got it, please edit question similarly for better clarity

Comment: Done, thanks for the input

Comment: Hello I have the same problem but don't understand what activities to chain in order to trigger my pipeline. I don't understand how to do step 2 and 3, do you have screenshots example please ?